# using for loops to compute a sequence

Tags: java

I want to write a program that will read an integer and then print the sum of the following sequence

```
1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3!+..........1/number! .
```

I should only use a for loop without using the math methods.
Here is my code and it works well but my question is, how can i print the sequence and then print the answer.

For example, if `x = 3` it should print `1 / 1 + 1 / 2 + 1 / 6 = 1.666667`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = input.nextInt();
double product = 1, sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    product *= i;
    sum += 1.0 / product;
}
System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);
```

Comment: You can print the String `1/product + ` at each iteration, with a small change for the last iteration.

Comment: Is there a hard limit on the number of decimal places in the final number? Your question specifies 6, but is that a hard limit, or just the number you wrote in the question?

Comment: @sara-chatila Please don't remove the question after you've gotten your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:-

```
import java.util.*;
class Number
{
 int fact(int n){
 int p=1;
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
 p*=i;
 }
 return p;
 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 Number num=new Number();
 int number;
 System.out.println("Enter the limit:-");
 number=sc.nextInt();
 double sum=0;
 for(int lo=1;lo<=number;lo++){
 sum+=(double)lo/(double)(num.fact(lo));
 }
 System.out.println("The sum is:- "+sum);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
int x= input.nextInt();
double product=1,sum=0;
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
    product*=i;
    sum+=1.0/product;
    System.out.print("1/" + product);

    if(i == x){
        System.out.print(" = " + sum);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(" + ");
    }
}
```

Rather than using println, use print and it will append to each line as it goes along.
You could even use println on the final one that prints the sum as this will give you a new line fore each execution if you were put it into a method and call it multiple times.

[Here is an ideone](http://ideone.com/UvQlKZ) with it working

It outputs this:

```
1/1.0 + 1/2.0 + 1/6.0 = 1.6666666666666667
```

If you don't want the denominators to have the decimal points, then make the product variable a `long` rather than a `double`.

---

Of course, what you've written works for small numbers, but factorials grow quite rapidly, and so too will your fractions, so it might be a better plan to use the BigDecimal class to represent the fractions rather than a double if you want the precision of the floating point number to be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code may be it helps you

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    int x= input.nextInt();
    double product=1,sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        product*=i;
        sum+=1.0/product;          
        System.out.print(""+i+"/"+(int)product+"+");
    }
    System.out.print("="+sum);
}
```

Output of Aboce Code is

```
1/1+2/2+3/6+=1.6666666666666667
```